# Need a XSLFO 1.1 to pdf converter with .NET and Java lib support

Tags: java, .net, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I am looking for a good conversion tool which basically transforms my xsl-fo(Extensible Stylesheet Language Formatting Objects) document (ver **XSLFO 1.1**) to PDF.

I cannot use Apache FOP cos it renders most of the objects conforming only till **XSLFO 1.0**

Also a prerequisite : it should expose libraries to use it from .NET or from Java environment.

There are quite a few formatters i found :

1. AHFormatter.
2. AltSoft - XML2PDF
3. Ibex - XMLPDF

Any good suggestions on this aspect would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about

- http://www.ecrion.com/Products/XFRenderingServer/Overview.aspx

There is also one named something like nitrox but I cannot recall right now.

When evaluating have a *very* close look on the memory consumption.  That will be the scalability bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for bringing up the point on mem. consumption.

I did tried XFRendering Server. Two strong that made not to go for it.

1. We want the same as a desktop solution. XFRenderingServer no doubt does my job quiet fast but we want the same in a desktop app.
2. Expensive. 
   Comes with a whopping price tag.(quiet misleading to what they have quoted on their website)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RenderX XEP](http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html) as desktop app, by running X4U.bat(in windows) or x4u.jar(in *nix OSs).

Regards